# Apache Flume 1.5 not giving expected results in Hadoop 2/Automatic fail-over cluster configuration

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

I have configured Apache Hadoop 2 cluster in HA/Automatic fail-over configuration on CentOS 6.5//64-bit. I have installed Flume 1.5 (apache-flume-1.5.0-bin.tar.gz).
I want to analyse twitter data using flume/Hive with some key words filtering. See image below:
[image]
Here are hadoop2 configuration file contents.(important properties only).

**core-site.xml**

```
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://mycluster</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property><name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name><value>nn1,nn2</value><final>true</final></property>
<property><name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn1</name><value>nn1.mycluster1.com:9000</value></property>
<property><name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.nn2</name><value>nn2.mycluster1.com:9000</value></property>
<property><name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn1</name><value>nn1.mycluster1.com:50070</value></property>
<property><name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.nn2</name><value>nn2.mycluster1.com:50070</value></property>
```

Here are flume configuration file contents:

**flume-env.sh**

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx200m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

**twitter.conf**

```
# Name the components on this agent
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel

# Describe/configure the source
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = **************
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = **********
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = **************
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = **************

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.maxBatchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.maxBatchDurationMillis = 1000

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords=hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, mapreduce, mahout, nosql

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.bind = localhost
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.port = 44444

# Describe the sink
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = logger
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=/user/flume/tweets/20140814/1_55
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.batchSize = 100
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.rollCount = 100
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.rollInterval = 100

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 1000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

I am executing following command.

```
flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file conf/twitter.conf --name TwitterAgent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

I have following questions/problems.

- a)-It seams keywords filtering is not working. Am I setting wrong
  property in configuration file?
- b)-This process is not copying any file on
  /user/flume/tweets/20140814/1_55 on hdfs.
- c)-Access Level of Twitter/API access token is Read-only. Do I need
  read-write access?
- d)-Is it correct way of using hdfs.path style, as I have used
  twitter.conf?
- e)-The process is executing and not stopping, not sure on what
  criteria it will stop.

It is continuing to show the following output.

```
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,000 docs
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Total docs indexed: 45,000, total skipped docs: 0
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     53 docs/second
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Run took 846 seconds and processed:
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     0.013 MB/sec sent to index
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     11.111 MB text sent to index
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: There were 0 exceptions ignored:
14/08/14 03:58:14 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:15 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:16 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,100 docs
14/08/14 03:58:16 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:17 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:18 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:18 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,200 docs
14/08/14 03:58:19 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:20 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,300 docs
14/08/14 03:58:20 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:21 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:22 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:22 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,400 docs
14/08/14 03:58:23 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:24 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:24 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,500 docs
14/08/14 03:58:25 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:26 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:26 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,600 docs
14/08/14 03:58:27 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:28 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:28 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,700 docs
14/08/14 03:58:29 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:30 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,800 docs
14/08/14 03:58:30 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:31 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:32 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:32 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 45,900 docs
14/08/14 03:58:33 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: 4F 62 6A 01 02 16 61 76 72 6F 2E 73 63 68 65 6D Obj...avro.schem }
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Processed 46,000 docs
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Total docs indexed: 46,000, total skipped docs: 0
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     53 docs/second
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: Run took 867 seconds and processed:
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     0.013 MB/sec sent to index
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO twitter.TwitterSource:     11.36 MB text sent to index
14/08/14 03:58:34 INFO twitter.TwitterSource: There were 0 exceptions ignored:
```

Can any body please help me, what I am missing?

Should I re-build Flume with Maven, before using for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to give read-write access to Twitter/API access token?
The way you have used hdfs.path style is also correct.

To fix the main issue ( not copying the files ), do the following changes:

**Changes in conf/twitter.conf file**

- a)-

Replace following line:
( TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = logger )

with following line:
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs

- b)-

Comment the following line:

```
#TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
```

Use following ( Apache Class )

```
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
```

**Changes in flume-env.conf**

Comment following: (no need to set this value)

```
#FLUME_CLASSPATH=""
```

Set proper values for the following attributes:

```
hdfs.filePrefix         
hdfs.fileSuffix         
hdfs.inUsePrefix        
hdfs.inUseSuffix        
hdfs.rollInterval       
hdfs.rollSize           
hdfs.rollCount          
hdfs.idleTimeout        
hdfs.batchSize          
hdfs.fileType   
hdfs.maxOpenFiles   
hdfs.minBlockReplicas   
hdfs.writeFormat    
hdfs.callTimeout    
hdfs.threadsPoolSize    
hdfs.rollTimerPoolSize  
hdfs.kerberosPrincipal  
hdfs.kerberosKeytab 
hdfs.proxyUser  
hdfs.round  
hdfs.roundValue 
hdfs.roundUnit  
hdfs.timeZone   
hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp  
hdfs.closeTries 
hdfs.retryInterval
```

To see more detail, see following link:

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

Answer (score 1):

Here you only see that events are being processed but you dont see the actual json file or json string that is brought out by these specific events. Maybe its because the sink being a 'logger', logging everything depending on your mode. To resolve:

on your log4j.properties, replace the configuration accordingly:

flume.root.logger=ALL,LOGFILE

cheers!

Comment: will check this property in log4j.properties